# easyphp / apache not able to connect to my dokuwiki with machines (virtuals and not virtual ones) on the same lan

Tags: windows, apache, easyphp, dokuwiki

I'm trying to setup a dokuwiki installed on an easyphp based on a windows distribution.

Nothing fancy so far

I can use the doku on my machine with the url `http://192.168.2.14:888`

Issue is I cannot access the wiki from another machine , virtual or not virtual one.

I thought it was an issue with the `httpd.conf`. I amended both part (see below)

```
<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-Webserver-14.1b2/binaries/httpserver/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And also the second part

```
<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-Webserver-14.1b2/modules">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I restarted the service and yet I still could not connect through any web browser with machines installed on my lan.

So I thought maybe it has something to do with the port

I did a `netstat -a -n` on the machine where I installed the easy php.

It seems to be listenning

[image]

I can ping `192.168.2.14 888` yet when I'm doing a `telnet 192.168.2.14 888`, I cannot connect.

So I disabled my firewall and still I cannot connect to my wiki through the web browser or telnet `192.168.2.14 888` it.

I do not have any more clues to where look at.

Any leads that will help me solve this issue , are more than welcomed.

Thanks

Update : I've done these steps since talking to Omar yesterday eve

- Change to `Listen 888`
- Change `Order allow,deny Allow from all` to just `Require all granted`

Comment: have you checked if you have the **Listen** directive on your httpd.conf?, it might by tied to a single machine http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_common.html#listen

Comment: Hi @Omar yes I do have it already `Listen 192.168.2.14:888`

Comment: did you try to change it to `Listen 888`? that will make to allow apache to accept request from everywhere

Comment: I did that too @Omar

Comment: so one other thing can be to change `Order allow,deny
    Allow from all` to just `Require all granted`, according to the documentation that is the equivalent on apache 2.4 https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: Hi @Omar I did that too and I still cannot display my webpage from another machine. Iif you have any other ideas, I'm all ears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to say it but using `easy php` , for a prototype usable by more than one machine on the same lan, is a real pain.

This is my way to have a quick dokuwiki prototype usable by all the availables machine on your lan:

- Install a linux virtual machine on your laptop (ubuntu server in my case)
- Install `apache2`, `php5` & `libapache2-mod-php5`
- Restart the apache2 service
- Copy your Doku folder in the folder `html`

And done. You can use your dokuwiki

Forget about easyphp and the likes